# php convert irc colors to html

Tags: php, colors, irc, color-codes

want to convert irc color codes to html via php. Here is the example: 
http://xvilo.com/logs.php on this server: http://digitalplace.nl/chat

it is a php logbot that log's everything into a database and then shows in the logs page! Now i want to find the color codes and convert them to this `<span class="[COLORNAME]">[MESSAGE]</span>`

I hope somebody can help me out!

Comment: The example page you linked requires a password.

Comment: Please give us the input and the expected output, btw you should really do something about the security of your website. I could login without filling a password, there is no index, and your script is vulnerable against sql injections. Please use mysqlior pdo. This was just a quick visit, there may be other vulnerabilities.

Comment: Well, you don't need a password for now! I cant post the irc log because the IRC color code is formatted like this, a 0x03 followed by one or two ascii numbers for foreground and background. So i can't post the 0x03 byte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, might be interesting.

https://metacpan.org/pod/IRC::Formatting::HTML